# How can I search for a movie based on its genre where genre is stored in a many-to-many table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get all columns of from table `movie` where genre.name="action"

I got a table `genre` that has genre.id and genre.name

I got another table `movie2genre` that has movieId and genreId

To get a list of genres by movie id, I can do the following

```
SELECT name FROM movie2genre
JOIN Genre on Genre.id = movie2genre.GenreId 
JOIN Movie on Movie.id = movie2genre.MovieId 
WHERE Movie.id = 15664
```

But i am not sure how to get a list of movies by genre name

for example, select all from movies where genre is 'action' or 'thriller'

Edit.

I need a query that works for  `'action' OR 'thriller'` and also  `'action' AND 'thriller'`

Comment: Same query... just `where Genre.Name = 'action'`, you'll want to modify your select to be movie.name also.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something?

```
SELECT movie.name FROM movie2genre
JOIN Genre on Genre.id = movie2genre.GenreId 
JOIN Movie on Movie.id = movie2genre.MovieId 
WHERE Genre.Name ='Action'
```

**UPDATE**

To perform an AND clause, use

```
      select name
from m
inner join mg on mg.movieid = m.movieid
inner join g on g.genreid = mg.genreid
where
g.genre = 'Action' or g.genre='Thriller'
group by name
having count(1) >= CASE WHEN OrClause then 1 else NumberOfGenresSupplied end
```

So numberofGenresSupplied would equal 2 in this case ( you can derive this from your submitted form).
OrClause would be set to true if you want any matched Genre, and false if it must match every matched Genre.

This will ensure a distinct list of films that meet at your genre criteria.

Comment: this works but does not work for `WHERE Genre.Name ='Action' AND genre.name = 'thriller'` because a movie can have more than one genre

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the WHERE clause to filter on the genre, just like you filtered on the movieid. Try this:

```
SELECT movie.name
FROM movie2genre
JOIN genre ON genre.id = movie2genre.genreid
JOIN movie ON movie.id = movie2genre.movieid
WHERE genre = 'action' OR genre = 'thriller';
```

**EDIT**
If you want to use AND to get both genres, you can do the same join, group by movieID and filter on having 2 rows. Try this:

```
SELECT movie.name
FROM movie2genre
JOIN genre ON genre.id = movie2genre.genreid
JOIN movie on movie.id = movie2genre.movieid
WHERE genre = 'action' OR genre = 'thriller'
GROUP BY movie.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Well can a movie have two genres?

Comment: @code578841441 I just saw your edit, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work!

---

```
SELECT 
    m.* 
FROM 
    Movie m
    inner join movie2genre  mg on m.MovieId = mg.MovieId
    inner join Genre g         on g.GenreId = mg.GenreId 
WHERE
    g.name = 'action' or g.name='thriller'
```

Comment: I am getting an error even though i do have a table called movie `Error Code: 1051. Unknown table 'movie'
`

Comment: With the alias `Movie m` the `SELECT` needs to be `SELECT m.*`

Comment: Try 'select m.*', just a mispell

Comment: That's because if the g.name = 'action' it cannot be also ='thriller'. That does not make sense. With 'AND' you should compare different things, for instance g.name = 'action' and m.name like '%Night%'

Comment: If a movie can have more than one classification you may use subqueries to achieve it in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

The OR case is simple, you can do it as a join as many have shown, or as an EXISTS.
The AND case is tricky because you have to go out and check two different rows. You can use two exists clauses.

AND...

```
SELECT name 
FROM Movie 
Where 
EXISTS (
 select *
 from movie2genre 
 JOIN Genre on Genre.id = movie2genre.GenreId 
 where Movie.id = movie2genre.MovieId 
   and genre = 'action'
)
and
EXISTS (
 select *
 from movie2genre 
 JOIN Genre on Genre.id = movie2genre.GenreId 
 where Movie.id = movie2genre.MovieId 
   and genre = 'thriller'
)
```

OR...

```
SELECT name 
FROM Movie 
Where 
EXISTS (
 select *
 from movie2genre 
 JOIN Genre on Genre.id = movie2genre.GenreId 
 where Movie.id = movie2genre.MovieId 
   and genre in ('action', 'thriller')
)
```

Another approach could be to count how many movie2genre match (using the OR approach). if the number is greater than zero, the OR is satisfied. If the number is equal to all the possible genres, the AND is also satisfied.